# Вылетает приложение при переходе между страницами

Tags: java, android

Есть приложение с несколькими activity. Хочу сделать переход на страницу регистрации, но почему то конкретно он не работает и приложение вылетает. С остальными страницами такого нет (страница еще не полностью готова, но все равно).
Я нуб, пишу можно сказать впервые, если кто-то поможет буду благодарен.  Пробовал создать полностью новую страницу, пустую, но даже на нее не работает переход, работает только с уже созданными activity. В чем может быть проблема?

xml -

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:onClick="openRegPage"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/CourseRecycler"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_cart_button" />
```

java -

```
public void openRegPage(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AuthAndReg.class);
        startActivity(intent);


    }
```

Может я что-то забыл?

Код страницы на которую надо перейти -

```
public class AuthAndReg extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText EdTextEmail, EdTextSecName, edName;

private DatabaseReference myDataBase;

private String USER_KEY = "User";







@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_auth_and_reg);
    init();
}

private void init()
{
    edName = findViewById(R.id.edName);
    EdTextSecName = findViewById(R.id.EdTextSecName);
    EdTextEmail = findViewById(R.id.EdTextEmail);
    myDataBase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(USER_KEY);
}


public void onClickAuth(View view){

}

public void onClickReg(View view){
    String id = myDataBase.getKey();
    String name = edName.getText().toString();
    String sec_name = EdTextSecName.getText().toString();
    String email = EdTextEmail.getText().toString();
    User NewUser = new User(id,name,sec_name,email);
    myDataBase.push().setValue(NewUser);

}




}
```

Logcat -

```
2022-06-23 15:54:11.601 27268-27301/com.example.defapp E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
2022-06-23 15:54:11.610 27268-27301/com.example.defapp E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
2022-06-23 15:54:58.327 27268-27268/com.example.defapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.defapp, PID: 27268
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.defapp/com.example.defapp.AuthAndReg}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class ImageButton
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class ImageButton
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class ImageButton
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.example.defapp:drawable/ic_button_reg with resource ID #0x7f0800bc
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_button_reg.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0800bc
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:820)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:630)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:877)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:819)
        at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:605)
        at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat$Api21Impl.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:864)
        at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:483)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:148)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:136)
        at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:66)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:64)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:86)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:73)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageButton(AppCompatViewInflater.java:226)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:141)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1565)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1616)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:772)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:706)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at com.example.defapp.AuthAndReg.onCreate(AuthAndReg.java:29)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
2022-06-23 15:54:58.328 27268-27268/com.example.defapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid pathData. Failure occurred at position 2 of path: STRING_TOO_LARGE
        at android.util.PathParser.nCreatePathDataFromString(Native Method)
        at android.util.PathParser.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.util.PathParser$PathData.<init>(PathParser.java:76)
        at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VFullPath.updateStateFromTypedArray(VectorDrawable.java:1931)
        at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VFullPath.inflate(VectorDrawable.java:1882)
        at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.inflateChildElements(VectorDrawable.java:741)
        at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.inflate(VectorDrawable.java:639)
        at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:142)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1295)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1254)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:807)
            ... 39 more
2022-06-23 15:55:01.650 27333-27363/com.example.defapp E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
2022-06-23 15:55:01.650 27333-27363/com.example.defapp E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
```

Comment: на вкладке Logcat у вас при вылете будет куча красного текста, его нужно вставить в вопрос, потому что пока сложно сказать в чем у вас беда

Comment: Проблема в векторной картинке: `Invalid pathData. Failure occurred at position 2 of path: STRING_TOO_LARGE`. Проверьте картинку, добавьте в вопрос если не разберётесь